# Tomcat not pushing updated HTML pages

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, redeploy

In a nutshell: html, xhtml, and jsp pages pushed from Eclipse to the wtpwebapps folder in Tomcat managed by Eclipse are not showing up in the browser as updated.

-- I have tried opening the page in a new browser (different browser, e.g. starting with Chrome and opening in Firefox after the file is updated on the server)

-- I have tried both true and false in Context.xml:reloadable, and in the Eclipse module configuration for "reloadable".

-- I have "touched" the new html file in the wtpwebapps/myapp folder to ensure it is dated "late".  I have also watched the redeploy process in Eclipse, and verified the file is moving as expected.

-- I have verified that the changes are showing up in the actual file contents in the deployed application folder in Tomcat.

-- I have cleaned the Tomcat work directory between each configuration change, and fully redeployed the web app

-- I have tried with html, xhtml (interpreted using MyFaces), and jsp files

-- the JSF and Tomcat publishing intervals are both set to 1 second

-- JSF is in Development mode

-- I have tried this in Tomcat 6.0.35 and Tomcat 7.0.30

Any ideas?

Comment: Additional data: updates *do* work on another project I'm working on, in the same Eclipse workspace, deployed to the same servers.  It has a nearly-identical web.xml, but it does *not* have the "JSF" facet activated in Eclipse. I am suspicious that activating that facet in Eclipse modified the project deployment configuration in a way I haven't discovered yet, resulting in the observed behavior.

Comment: It turns out, the problem was *entirely* the result of having a context.xml file in META-INF.  Even an empty Context element causes the behavior.  Once that file is removed, Tomcat updates cleanly.